# Do not fire Form Validation in angular 2 on blur

Tags: validation, angular

I was able to integrate form validation in angular 2.

I am using `form = formBuilder.group({...})` method.

Validations work good. But I want validation to be fired only when I click submit. Currently by default it fires up when user blur from an input. How to stop firing validation on blur and fire it manual.

**EDIT:**

Problem with using `*ngIf` or `[hidden]` is that they work fine with variables to keep track of form submission. **But** validation only fires when i blur from the input. In other way validation does not fire when user has not visited the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to integrate a custom `formSubmitted` property into your expression to display errors. For example:

```
<span *ngIf="formSubmitted && form.controls.someCtrl.errors?.someerror">
  Some message
</span>
```

By default its value is `false` and will be set to `true` when the form is submitted.

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmitted()">
    </form>
  `
})
export class SomeComponent {
  formSubmitted: boolean = false;

  onFormSubmitted() {
    this.formSubmitted = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could leverage the `touched` property: `form.touched`.

Comment: yes that was another issue. I was using touched property. In the sense that show only if touched.

Answer (score 1):

Show the errors only when the submitted flat is set:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="submit()" ...>
 <input ngControl="name" #name="ngForm" type="text">
 <span [hidden]="name.valid && isSubmitted"><b>Required</b></span>
 </form>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  isSubmitted:boolean = false;

  submit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Maybe you are facing a different problem. Currently when a number input is required an empty input doesn't make it invalid but otherwise and required field is invalid when it was not visited.

Comment: yes that was another issue. I was using touched property.